# How can I use downloadable content on a phone app while not using any storage on the database?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create an app where you can convert youtube videos to mp4 videos.
When you download a video, it will be stored locally on your phone and not on the database, but that it still is linked to the database so that the videos are linked to your account.

I am new to the database world and I have not much experience in in-app downloads, so could someone help me out please?

I am using flutter and firebase firestore for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use flutter_downloader https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader
and path provider https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider